# Excel - Fill with blocks of dates

Tags: excel, fill

I am looking to fill a spreadsheet with data repeating data, so 25 appointments for today, 25 appointments for tomorrow with the same name and so on for as far as possible.

Is the a simple way of filling the table where the date increases in blocks of 25?

[Example of what i am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cRWK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this you might be able to achieve what you want ,any problems shout out

```
       'to change the date to the next day
       Public Function ExtraDay(strDate As String)
       Dim tDay As Date
       tDay = Format(DateAdd("d", 1, strDate), "dd/mm/yy")
       ExtraDay = tDay

        End Function

       'gets the last used row
        Function getThelastUsedRowAddress() As Integer
        'Get Last Row in Worksheet UsedRange
         Dim LastRow As Range, ws As Worksheet
         Set ws = ActiveSheet
          MsgBox ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

          getThelastUsedRowAddress = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
          End Function

          'button command on the sheet
           Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
            Dim n, t As Integer
            Dim ns As String
            n = getThelastUsedRowAddress()
            t = n + n
            ns = CStr(t)
            Call getThelastUsedRow(CStr(n))
             Call TheLoopRange(CStr(n) + 1, ns)
             End Sub

           'get the last used and paste after
            Sub getThelastUsedRow(address As String)
           'Get Last Row in Worksheet UsedRange
             Dim LastRow As Range, ws As Worksheet
             Dim numcopied As Integer
            Dim numonpaper As Integer
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
             numcopied = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
               numonpaper = numcopied + 1
               ws.UsedRange.Copy 'Destination:=Wst.Cells(1, 1)

               'paste
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & numonpaper).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                 End Sub
                 'loop the pasted range and change date to the next day from date
                  Sub TheLoopRange(rangestart As String, rangeend As String)
                    'rangestart,rangeend
                  Dim rCell As Range
                  Dim rRng As Range

                  Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("E" & rangestart & ":E" & rangeend)

                 For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
                'MsgBox rCell.Value
                  rCell.Value = ExtraDay(rCell.Value)
                   Next rCell

                    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets as assume that:

1. We use Sheet1
2. Company column is column D
3. Date column is column I

Pease try:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Test()

        Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To Lastrow
                If i = 2 Then
                    .Cells(i, 9).Value = Date + 1
                ElseIf i <> 2 And .Cells(i, 4).Value = 1 Then
                        .Cells(i, 9).Value = .Cells(i, 9).Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
                Else: .Cells(i, 9).Value = .Cells(i, 9).Offset(-1, 0).Value
                End If

            Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```